# Mapped types & generic function typing error

Tags: typescript

I wrote a fairly straightforward mapped-types based code, which doesn't want to type check for some reason.

First, define input and output:

```
interface Validated<T> {
  valid: boolean;
  value: T;
} 

interface FieldInputs {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

interface ParsedFields {
  name: Validated<string>;
  price: Validated<number>;
}
```

Define parser types and parser map:

```
type FieldKey = keyof FieldInputs & keyof ParsedFields;
type FieldParser<F extends FieldKey> = (value?: FieldInputs[F]) => ParsedFields[F];
type FieldParsers = {
  [F in FieldKey]: FieldParser<F>;
};

declare let fieldParsers: FieldParsers;
```

Now this very simple generic function fails to type-check:

```
function update<F extends FieldKey>(field: F, value: FieldInputs[F]) {
  const parser: FieldParser<F> = fieldParsers[field];
  parser.apply(value);
}
```

gives the following error (`--strictFunctionTypes`):

```
Type 'FieldParsers[F]' is not assignable to type 'FieldParser<F>'.
  Type 'FieldParser<"name"> | FieldParser<"price">' is not assignable to type 'FieldParser<F>'.
    Type 'FieldParser<"name">' is not assignable to type 'FieldParser<F>'.
      Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible.
        Type 'FieldInputs[F]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
          Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
            Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

What am I missing?

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Validated%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20valid%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20value%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FieldInputs%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20price%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20ParsedFields%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20name%3A%20Validated%3Cstring%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20price%3A%20Validated%3Cnumber%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20FieldKey%20%3D%20keyof%20FieldInputs%20%26%20keyof%20ParsedFields%3B%0D%0Atype%20FieldParser%3CF%20extends%20FieldKey%3E%20%3D%20(value%3F%3A%20FieldInputs%5BF%5D)%20%3D%3E%20ParsedFields%5BF%5D%3B%0D%0Atype%20FieldParsers%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%5BF%20in%20FieldKey%5D%3A%20FieldParser%3CF%3E%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20let%20fieldParsers%3A%20FieldParsers%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20update%3CF%20extends%20FieldKey%3E(field%3A%20F%2C%20value%3A%20FieldInputs%5BF%5D)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20const%20parser%3A%20FieldParser%3CF%3E%20%3D%20fieldParsers%5Bfield%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20parser.apply(value)%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A)

Comment: There is no error in playground

Comment: @Niladri you need to enable `--strictFunctionTypes` - it seems that playground options are not shared in the link.

Comment: it's because it does not allow bivariant assignation , where you are assigning an union type "string"|number to `fieldParsers[field]` which is of type string only. You can only assign base/super type to derived type with this case .i.e `number = string` is not allowed

Comment: check this link here https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html ..

Comment: @Niladri I am not assigning anything to `fieldParsers[field]`. I am _reading_ its value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is protecting you against something unlikely to happen, and you need to decide how to work around it (spoiler alert: use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions))

---

Imagine if I do this:

```
const field = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "name" : "price";
const value = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "Widget" : 9.95;
update(field, value); // no error
```

In this case, `field` is of the type `FieldKey` and `value` is of the type `FieldInputs[FieldKey]`, and there is a 50% chance that they don't match up.  Despite this, the compiler does not warn you: it infers that `F` is `FieldKey` (which is a perfectly valid thing for it to do), and the call to `update()` is allowed.

Inside the implementation of `update()`, there is the warning that `FieldParsers[F]` might not be a `FieldParser<F>`.  If `F` is `FieldKey` as above, this mismatch becomes apparent.  `FieldParsers[F]` will be `FieldParser<'name'> | FieldParser<'price'>`, but `FieldParser<F>` is `FieldParser<'name' | 'price'>`.   The former is *either* something that parses a `string` *or* something that parses a `number`.  The latter is something that parses *either* a `string` or a `number`.  These are not the same (due to [contravariance of function parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-6.html#strictFunctionTypes) enabled with `--strictFunctionTypes`).  The difference between these types is exposed when the code above ends up calling `update("name", 9.95)` and you try to parse a `number` with a `string` parser.   You want a `FieldParser<F>`, but all you have is a `FieldParsers[F]`.

---

Now backing up, is someone *likely* to play games like this where `F` is a union of values?  If so, then you might want to change your definition of `update()` to explicitly prohibit `F` from being anything but a single string literal.  Something like...

```
type NotAUnion<T, U = T> =
  U extends any ? [T] extends [U] ? T : never : never;

declare function update<F extends FieldKey>(
  field: F & NotAUnion<F>, 
  value: FieldInputs[F]
);
```

But that is probably overkill, and it *still* doesn't resolve the warning inside the implementation of `update()`.  The compiler is simply not smart enough to understand that the value of `F` is a single string literal value and that what you are doing is safe.

To make that error go away, you will probably want to do a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).  Either you know that nobody is likely to intentionally shoot themselves in the foot by widening `F` to `FieldKey`, or you have prevented the caller from doing this by using something like `NotAUnion`.  In either case, you can tell the compiler that you know that `fieldParsers[field]` will be a valid `FieldParser<F>`:

```
function update<F extends FieldKey>(field, value: FieldInputs[F]) {
  const parser = fieldParsers[field] as FieldParser<F>; // okay
  parser.apply(value);
}
```

So that works.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: You are correct that problems come from the fact that compiler imagines `F` to be union type. In your first sample `F="name"|"price"`.

"The compiler is simply not smart enough to understand that the value of F is a single string literal value and that what you are doing is safe."

Do you think this smartness has a name? Should I file a bug?

Comment: I don't know... it's not a bug exactly, just a limitation of the kinds of type analysis the compiler can do.  As for the name, not sure.  I think I might have seen similar issues filed before but my searches are not bringing anything up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have gone a little bit overboard with the types. Simplifying them will actually solve your problem.

Let's start by looking at your type definition for `FieldParser`:

```
type FieldParser<F extends FieldKey> = (value?: FieldInputs[F]) => ParsedFields[F];
```

All it is really doing is accepting a value and returning a `Validated` object of the same type. We can simplify this down to:

```
type FieldParser<T> = (value?: T) => Validated<T>;
```

That not only improves the complexity, but it also greatly improves the readability of the type.

Note, however, that this does mean we have lost the restriction on `FieldParser` that it only can be used with keys from `FieldKey`. But in reality, if you think about the generic concept of a "Field Parser", it should be generic, and as we will see in a second, this doesn't mean your consuming code becomes any less strict.

We can also then build `FieldParsers` as a generic type

```
type FieldParsers<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: FieldParser<K>;
}
```

Then the rest of the code can use those without issue:

```
interface MyFieldInputs {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

declare let fieldParsers: FieldParsers<MyFieldInputs>;

function update<T extends keyof MyFieldInputs>(field: T, value: MyFieldInputs[T]) {
  const parser = fieldParsers[field];
  parser.apply(value);
}
```

However, we can do even better. You still have to use `parser.apply(value)` here, when really you should be able to simply call `parser(value)`.

Let's take the generics one step further, and rather than hardcoding the `update` function to make use of the specific `fieldParsers` variable that we defined before the function, let's use a function to build the update function.

```
function buildUpdate<TInputs>(parsers: FieldParsers<TInputs>) {
  return function update<T extends keyof TInputs>(field: T, value: TInputs[T]) {
    const parser = parsers[field];
    parser(value);
  }
}
```

By doing that, we can easily tie together all the types, and Typescript will simply accept (and typecheck) calling `parser(value)`.

So now, putting it all together, you end up with:

```
interface Validated<T> {
  valid: boolean;
  value: T;
} 

/**
 * Generic field validator
 */
type FieldParser<T> = (value?: T) => Validated<T>;

/**
 * Generic set of field validators for a specific set of field types
 */
type FieldParsers<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: FieldParser<T[K]> 
}

function buildUpdate<TInputs>(parsers: FieldParsers<TInputs>) {
  return function update<T extends keyof TInputs>(field: T, value: TInputs[T]) {
    const parser = parsers[field];
    parser(value);
  }
}
```

And you would make use of it by doing:

```
interface MyFieldInputs {
  name: string;
  price: number;
}

declare let fieldParsers: FieldParsers<MyFieldInputs>;

const update = buildUpdate(fieldParsers);

update('name', 'new name'); // Fully type checked

update('name', 5); // ERROR
```

Comment: This `type FieldParser<T> = (value?: T) => Validated<T>;` doesn't work for me. In reality my input/output values differ. (E.g. input can be a string, output - parsed phone number).

Yes, by making this critical simplification you will make the code simpler and correct, but this is not what I wont. I want to use two interfaces (Input & Output) to type-check function implementation.

Comment: Ah, I see. So just because `price` in your `FieldInputs` interface is `number`, you may want the type of that field once validated to be like `Validated<CurrencyAmount>`?

Comment: Yes. I have lots of such interface pairs with different sets of parsers. And I’m writing some generic code for working with such sets (combination, aggregation)