# Is there a way to prevent union types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

I'm new to conditional types, so I tried the most obvious static way, no success:

```
type NoUnion<Key> =
  Key extends 'a' ? 'a' :
  Key extends 'b' ? 'b' :
  never;

type B = NoUnion<'a'|'b'>;
```

The B type is still a union. Would somebody please school me?

Here's a [playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20NoUnion%3CKey%3E%20%3D%0A%20%20Key%20extends%20'a'%20%3F%20'a'%20%3A%0A%20%20Key%20extends%20'b'%20%3F%20'b'%20%3A%0A%20%20never%3B%0A%0Atype%20B%20%3D%20NoUnion%3C'a'%7C'b'%3E%3B).

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon Solve [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50628086/592641)

Comment: What would you expect `B` to be instead of a union?

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin in the example, a `never`. In use, an `'a'` or a `'b'`.

Comment: The union type in your type argument passes two of the conditional types in `NoUnion`, so you end up with `a|b`. The conditional type doesn't stop when the first condition passes.

Comment: @Fenton oooooh, I got it. It checks each member independently. You can put it as an answer.

Comment: @Birowsky When you pass `a | b`, `Key` extends both `a` and `b`; you're only supposed to get `never` when `Key` extends neither.

Comment: @Birowsky - I didn't add it as an answer as it only explains how the code works in your question... but doesn't actually help you to solve the problem. See if Titian's great answer helps to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I am unsure what the usecase for this is, but we can force the `NoUnion` to `never` if the passed type is a union type.

As other mentioned conditional types distribute over a union, this is called [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html)

> Conditional types in which the checked type is a naked type parameter are called distributive conditional types. Distributive conditional types are automatically distributed over union types during instantiation. For example, an instantiation of T extends U ? X : Y with the type argument A | B | C for T is resolved as (A extends U ? X : Y) | (B extends U ? X : Y) | (C extends U ? X : Y).

The key there is 'naked type', if we wrap the type in a tuple type for example the conditional type will no longer be distributive.

```
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never 

type NoUnion<Key> =
    // If this is a simple type UnionToIntersection<Key> will be the same type, otherwise it will an intersection of all types in the union and probably will not extend `Key`
    [Key] extends [UnionToIntersection<Key>] ? Key : never; 

type A = NoUnion<'a'|'b'>; // never
type B = NoUnion<'a'>; // a
type OtherUnion = NoUnion<string | number>; // never
type OtherType = NoUnion<number>; // number
type OtherBoolean = NoUnion<boolean>; // never since boolean is just true|false
```

The last example is an issue, since `boolean` is seen by the compiler as `true|false`, `NoUnion<boolean>` will actually be `never`. Without more details of what exactly you are trying to achieve it is difficult to know if this is a deal breaker, but it could be solved by treating `boolean` as a special case:

```
type NoUnion<Key> =
    [Key] extends [boolean] ? boolean :
    [Key] extends [UnionToIntersection<Key>] ? Key : never;
```

Note: `UnionToIntersection` is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50374908/transform-union-type-to-intersection-type)

Comment: @Birowsky :)) There are no upvotes in writing docs :P. This is more fun ;)

Comment: So.. I tried implementing this towards my problem, but all I get is a broken TS :/ If you could [take a look here](http://jsbin.com/yebuner/1/edit?js), I'd be sooo grateful! The goal is to fix the problem within the resolver without assertion. (It's a jsbin because the playground link was too big for comment)

Comment: @Birowsky looking into it

Comment: @Birowsky Maybe this would be workable: `function resolver<cmdName extends CommandName>(a: Command<cmdName>): NoUnion<cmdName> extends never ? never : CommandToHandler[cmdName]['out'] {
    return handlers[a.kind](a);
  }

  let c : Command<"a">
  resolver(c) // ok 
  let cu : Command<"a" | "b">
  resolver(cu) // returns never  `

Comment: Sorry mate, but it doesn't fix the `Error:(26, 10) TS2349: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. Type '((arg: Command<"a">) => number) | ((arg: Command<"b">) => string)' has no compatible call signatures.` You should see this problem if you paste the  snippet from jsbin to TS playground. Thanx, and sorry for not being explicit.

Comment: @Birowsky yeah .. inside the function the union will still be there no way I know of to get around that … the call will return never if it's invoked with a union ..

Comment: How about now? :}

Answer (score 8):

By the way, the "simpler" one I was trying to come up with looks like this:

( NOTE: the following doesn't work in TS after v3.3, due to [microsoft/TypeScript#34504](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34504):

```
// type NotAUnion<T> = [T] extends [infer U] ? 
//  U extends any ? [T] extends [U] ? T : never : never : never;
```

instead one can use the following since defaults still get instantiated before distribution, at least for now: )

```
type NotAUnion<T, U = T> =
  U extends any ? [T] extends [U] ? T : never : never;
```

This should work (please test it; not sure why I got the original version in [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50611240/2887218) wrong but it's fixed now ).  It's a similar idea to the `UnionToIntersection`: you want to make sure that a type `T` is assignable to each part of `T` if you distribute it.  In general that's only true if `T` is a union with just one constituent part (which is also called "not a union").

Anyway, @TitianCernicovaDragomir's answer is perfectly fine also.  Just wanted to get this version out there.  Cheers.

Comment: Cheers monsieur! By the way, I thought the brackets in `[T]` were only used for tuples. But here it seems to have some other semantics. Could you clarify please? (A link to a resource is perfectly fine)

Comment: Yeah, it *is* used as a tuple, in a hacky way meant to prevent distributing.  (See @TitianCD's comment about "naked type" above).  Let's see if I can find a link.

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21870) is the closest I can find, with not much explanation. `T extends U ? X : Y` distributes `T` if `T` is a "naked type parameter". The idea is to "clothe" it: `[T] extends [U]` should hold if and only if `T extends U` (since single-element tuples are covariant in their type) but prevents the distribution of `T`.  There's nothing special about using tuple syntax here; any covariant type will do: `{x: T} extends {x: U}` holds if and only if `T extends U` hold.  But `[T]` is probably the shortest way to do it.

Comment: That is a neat solution. But somehow, it doesn't work in versions > `3.3.3` (last version I could test in the playground). You can compare [`3.3.3`](https://tsplay.dev/DmMezm) with [`3.5.1`](https://tsplay.dev/Lw6JGw). It seems like an inferred type parameter `U` cannot be made "naked" anymore to create distributed union type - sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: @ford04 Thank you for pointing that out.  I see [microsoft/TypeScript#34504](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34504) mentions this, so I guess I have to find and change any answers of mine that relied on the prior behavior (not that such things are easy to search for)

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
type NoUnion<T, U = T> = T extends U ? [U] extends [T] ? T : never : never;
```