# Use typescript to force objects in array to have same fields for all indexes in array

Tags: arrays, typescript, object

I have run into a scenario where I would like the following type-enforcement:

I want the type `MyArrayType` to be an array of objects. The fields in the objects must be identical for each object-index in the array, but the 'catch' is that I do not know the fields beforehand. I would like them to be 'inferred'.

Here is an example of how the typing would work:

```
const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [{ foo: 2 }, { foo: 1 }]                   // this will work

const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [{ foo: 2 }, { bar: 1 }]                   // this will fail

const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [{ bar: 2 }, { bar: 1 }]                   // this will work

const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [{ anyFieldName: 2 }, { anyFieldName: 1 }] // this will work

const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [{ bar: 2, foo: 1 }, { bar: 1, foo: 2  }]  // this will work

const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [{ bar: 2, foo: 1 }, { bar: 1 }]           // this will fail
```

The following should also fail:

```
const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [1,2,3].map((number) => {
  if (number === 2) {
    return {
      foo: 1
      bar: 2
    }
  }
  
  return {
    bar: 2
  }
})
```

And this should work:

```
const myArrayType: MyArrayType = [1,2,3].map((number) => {      
  return {
    foo: 1
    bar: 2
  }
})
```

Is this possible to achieve with typescript as of 2021?

**Additional constraints:**

- Compile-time checking. Runtime checking is useful but not required.
- Wrapper functions and helpers are OK.
- Ideally, the function applies excess property checking as well, throwing errors if unexpected extra properties are present on values beyond the first.

Comment: Are you trying to make an API to be used with array literals as you have here, or is this meant to check at runtime as well? Are you open to wrapping the expression in a function call or other helper?

Comment: First and foremost; just for static typing, not runtime. But I would like to check at runtime IF I can get the typing to work.

I am open to a wrapper, and yes I am building a email-notifier service/api.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to learn about generics?

Comment: I am familiar with generics. You mean writing something like:

const myArrayType: MyArrayType<{ foo: number }>

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can express the first part of this with this generic function:

```
function check<T1, T2 extends T1>(t1: T1, ...tRest: T2[]): T1[] {
  return [t1, ...tRest];
}

// Accepts an entire array, courtesy Jeff Mercado (thank you!).
function checkArray<T1, T2 extends T1>(arr: [T1, ...T2[]]): T1[] { 
  return arr;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-skgb82JDgjD4bxUWBhI4xNjUJ61zh+U9RVTfq+q18KL2efzSkjIOMYI653Lrr6ZEGNaYdbYGymMwWSxW5SbYHHWynuxzYY7xe7EK6lxhA9I92HKeuaYbr08GLWzak6NWobCa5OG7LLp3NwRSJHR-r2bRZ4+WZe0itgWTQEicCRJJY5KUtStLDB+WSMsyrJgByXI8ny5CCkEZSKmKYCSuKrIqqq6qamw2pgLq+qGvOOA2hAdp2kAA)

As far as the `map` is concerned, TypeScript correctly infers the union return type of the callback function. Your best bet there is probably to "prohibit" a union by forcing the type to `never`, as you can do with existing tools like [this example by Titian Cernicova-Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50641073/1426891):

> ```
> type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
>     (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void)
>     ? I : never 
>
> type NoUnion<Key> =
>     // If this is a simple type UnionToIntersection<Key> will be the same type,
>     // otherwise it will an intersection of all types in the union and probably
>     // will not extend `Key`
>     [Key] extends [UnionToIntersection<Key>] ? Key : never;
> ```

Comment: The check function in the first part of the answer works great. The second part of the answer is a bit more unclear for now. I'm looking into a way to pass the actual array into the check function, rather than the first element, then the rest.

Comment: @johann1301s Since you might or might not want runtime checks, I figured you'd have a better sense than me whether you'd want to guard the function passed into `map` or guard the return value from `map`. They'd both be reasonable places to use NoUnion and also do a runtime check, but the implementation would be different depending on which you try.

Comment: @johann1301s: as written, you'd call it like `check(...arr)`. But you can change the signature so you could pass the array as an argument instead. `<T1, T2 extends T1>(arr: [T1, ...T2[]]): T1[] => arr`

Comment: Wow, that second check signature works very well.

Comment: @JeffM Nice! If you post that as its own answer, I'd upvote, or I (or someone) can edit it in above. Either way, though, I don't think it will quite get you to where you want with something as dynamic as `map`.

Comment: This is great, but I see one edge case with the (original) check function from your answer @JeffBowman. If the first parameter is {}, anything can be passed as second argument and it works either way. See this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgTwIICcUEMEBUEAcCmAjDALwzAAW+wA1gBQDeAvgDQwMwBG6KAXDMSYBKGAHpRMKBQCWEGBAogArgBsAJjBT50KlQhgAzdNJVtOS2GpD45YELADm0gG74Y+NCBQAob6EiwiKgY2Hj4AEyk5FS0jKySKEr4IuKSMnIKyuqa2rr6RiZmFjBWNjB2ji5uHihevgZKYMBQ0uDR1DQAPFiEbFiR+AAeUPhganI9AHx0UIT8PWwAdMtQAEo2UPPhANoAukLzhHvs3jA5UEooYDDbs0sr69C7ANzeTN5AA).

Comment: @johann1301s But that's true: every instance matches or extends `{}`. What would you have it do instead?

Comment: Good question @JeffBowman. Maybe only allow non empty object literals as first parameter. That is; somehow extending the T1 param.

Comment: It would be optimal if the check method gave an error if you include any additional keys in any object that is missing in the first object in the array. See this [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/N4KABGDGD2B2DOAXMBbAngQQE5YIZoBU0AHAUwEYwBeKAC1MgGsAKYAXwBoxgwAzaaAC4wlNgEoIkqdJnSA9HLDxa0AK4AbACZgA5gEsAbqTCkc0LCHBQ4SVJhz4iZAEzU6DFj35CRYTtz4BYXIuACNcLGC-CVkwBSUVDW19IxMzCyteVVhIRD04dyYAHgIQsAJXUgAPRFJYTXhy8gA+ZkRyYVKuADpexAAlUiRO5wBtAF0xTvIJ7isILFJEVSxYMFH2nr7BpHGAbis2ECOQIA) for examples. I am looking for a way for this to work.

Comment: @johann1301s You'd be fighting structural typing, but you might consult here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54775790/1426891 . BTW, as your needs get more  specific, the more they belong as edits to the original question rather than elaborations in my answer's comments, or perhaps they belong as another question altogether. (Not that I mind, but the shape of StackOverflow is intended for all constraints to be in the question so it is easier to find and answer later. Once answers start coming in, editing in new constraints can invalidate answers and make everything hard to follow.)