# Generic function picking one property

Tags: typescript

I was trying to create a generic function transforming an object by filtering only one property - sth along the lines of:

```ts
function pickOnePropertyUntyped(data: any, key: any): any {
  return {
    [key]: data[key]
  }
}
```

Thus desired behaviour is:

```
const a: A = {
  a: 'a',
  b: 1
}
const r = pickOnePropertyUntyped(a, 'a'); // {'a': 'a'}
```

I am having problems with getting desired types and implementation.

My attempt is:

```ts
type UnionToIntersection<U> = 
    (U extends any ? (k: U)=>void : never) extends ((k: infer I)=>void) ? I : never 

type NoUnion<Key> =
    [Key] extends [UnionToIntersection<Key>] ? Key : never; 

type PickOneProperty<T, P extends keyof T & string> = {
  [K in keyof T as K extends NoUnion<P> ? K : never]: T[K]
}

function pickOneProperty<T, K extends keyof T & string>(
   data: T,
   key: K,
): PickOneProperty<T, K> {
  return {
    [key]: data[key]
  }
}
```

Which:

- correctly restricts input property to only one key (I used [Is there a way to prevent union types in TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50639496/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-union-types-in-typescript))
- correctly infer output type

Unfortunately, it flags return type as incorrect.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAglC8UDeBYAUFKBDAXFAzsAE4CWAdgOYA06mARnmQK4C2dER6AvuuqJFACqZEgHsyAFVEBJMsA74IAY2BiyAHkEA%20BFFqYoACkFQIAD3lkAJvmxkQUAPxGA1nkEBKeFoBuoklZQjBA%20HB6mFhDWtoaGblDkAGYcUNJevv5W4c7SQVBkISm8aPzQAHKiwmrqANIQIDrw%20pgA2nUgALoRljZQLVXiUrLyRIoq1e1aXc7teQWhRADcemh84NAACiRKLgDyBRtEopBEoOoSVFAb3VG9LvWiiVASUABkBMTkFI3I%20m0JZCg9xAj2e2FsNRu0SgFQGGg2Ohmc0KRA6eAkbQ63GKawEEgghC2O32EEOxw4oF0RL2ByOJzOMEuAHIsEytMUlOJCNg8HBEKgMDyoCymTRBQwoABGbGrNCJJhkcbiKBgbY00l0ikgc6XSHmHq2YGgl7vQikShaQzNKxYYC4Z5igzAvA1MUePDUklk%20nai5QGo6AWYIgQYBMIiAoMGFrAtFQG12mP1LGCnhoNPoTlkbkh-BMAA2wF0quJtPJpxAhiwzNZHkWma5onzEAAdPnRBRDLmC8A60A)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are observing here is more or less a missing feature in TypeScript. Most of the times when you are trying to use a computed property key, TypeScript automatically adds an *index signature* to the type of the object. There are only some exceptions; for example when the type of the key is already a known *string literal* type ([as shown here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGHsDsGcBcAICGAueAiRb4F52ZBDAgEY7wDew88A2ogLqoCMATAMzAC%20QA)). See discussions about this problem [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13948).

The index signature breaks the typing here. As far as I know, there are no *"satisfying"* solutions to this problem. Even a normal type assertion does not work here as TypeScript sees *no overlap* between the two types. What you can do is to assert to `unkown` first and then to `PickOneProperty<T, K>`

```
function pickOneProperty<T, K extends keyof T & string>(
   data: T,
   key: K,
): PickOneProperty<T, K> {
  return {
    [key]: data[key]
  } as unknown as PickOneProperty<T, K>
}
```

Just be aware that there is pretty much no type-safety in this implementation now.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)